# php error permission denied с правами на всё - 777

Tags: php, linux, access-control

На весь каталог с сайтами выставил права `777` (`ugo=rwx`), и владельца `www:data` (под ним работают *apache*, *php*).

Всё равно не могу удалять и писать файлы в *php*.

Почему так?

p.s. Находил что-то про *Access Control List*, но так и не разобрался, что именно нужно сделать. Так же хотелось бы чтоб все работало с правами `755` (`u=rwx,go=rx`).

Comment: Рекурсивно выставляли?

Comment: рекурсивно поменять права и принадлежность: 1. каталоги: `sudo find /path/to/docroot -type d -exec chmod u=rwx,go=rx {} +` 2. файлы: `sudo find /path/to/docroot -type f -exec chmod u=rw,go=r {} +` 3. принадлежность: `sudo chown -R www:data /path/to/docroot`

Comment: возможно, ошибка происходит при попытке записи в файлы, лежащие за пределами *docroot-а*. в логах должен быть написан полный путь к вызвавшим ошибку файлам.

Comment: *acl*: для возможности выставлять права на их (*acl*) основе раздел должен быть примонтирован с опцией *acl*. смотрите вывод команды `mount | grep acl`.

Comment: ещё блокировать доступ могут такие «вещи» как *selinux*, *apparmor* и т.п. если это не *redhat*-основный дистрибутив, то, скорее всего ничего из перечисленного в системе не стоит.

Comment: Сделал как вы написали - работает! Спасибо

Comment: Сейчас делал, опять столкнулся
Message: move_uploaded_file(data/content/img-afisha.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied  
Message: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpr2tlbc' to 'data/content/img-afisha.jpg' Я что-то не до конца сделал?

Comment: приведите вывод команды `$ ls -ld /tmp /tmp/phpr2tlbc /путь/к/data/content` (подставив полный путь к упомянутому в ошибке каталогу `data/content` — он где-то в *docroot-е* сайта должен находиться).

Comment: @sanu, и упоминайте меня явно с помощью `@alex` (достаточно только начальных букв логина) — я не получаю уведомлений без такого упоминания, потому что в комментариях отметился ещё один человек.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin ls: невозможно получить доступ к /tmp/phpr2tlbc: Нет такого файла или каталога
drwxr-xr-x 694 sanu sanu 16384 июля 10 00:16 /sites/test/www/data/content
drwxrwxrwt 8 root root 4096 июля 10 22:49 /tmp

Comment: `drwxr-xr-x 694 sanu sanu 16384 июля 10 00:16 /sites/test/www/data/content` — этот каталог принадлежит пользователю `sanu`, группе `sanu`, остальным в этот каталог запись запрещена. вы же изменяли принадлежность всех каталогов. откуда вдруг взялся этот каталог, принадлежащий не www-data?

Comment: кстати, сейчас мельком глянул на свой первый комментарий. там скопировано `www;data`, видимо, из вашего вопроса. а должно быть `www-data:www-data`.

Comment: Теперь работает, попробовал тот же файл, нормально удалило и записало. Спасибо Вам!

Comment: @alexanderbarakin мне интересно, почему я с под своего пользователя без root, не могу ничего скопироать в эту папку с сайтами? Что нужно сделать чтоб это было возможно?

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25722/discussion-between-alexander-barakin-and-sanu0074).

Answer (score 1):

рекурсивно поменять права и принадлежность можно, например, так:

1. каталоги:

   ```
   $ sudo find /path/to/docroot -type d -exec chmod u=rwx,go=rx {} +
   ```
2. файлы:

   ```
   $ sudo find /path/to/docroot -type f -exec chmod u=rw,go=r {} +
   ```
3. принадлежность:

   ```
   $ sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/docroot
   ```